# Merging unallocated space to existing partition in Raid5

Tags: partition, dell-poweredge, raid5

I have Dell PowerEdge Server T310 built with a Raid5 (3 x 300gb)
Windows Server 2008 R2
SAS controller PERC H700.

I have recently added a 4th drive 300gb thru Dell’s application “Openmanage”. The whole procedure went well.
Now I want to merge the unallocated space with the Datapart1 (see below), the system does not permit to extend volume, and when I try to format the unallocated space I get an error saying “the disk already contains the maximum number of partition”.

My question is;
How do I do it?
Do I have to copy all data from Datapart1 to a spare drive, delete the partition and recreate a new one using all the space available?
Or is there another way?

Tried to post snap shot of disk, but I don’t have enough reputation, sorry.

39 mb       no name - (OEM Partition),
3.00 gb Recovery - (System, Active, Primary Partition),
40.00 gb    OS (C:) - (Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition),
514.71  gb  Datapart1 (D:) - (Logical Drive),
278.88 gb   Unallocated

Comment: Can you describe what happens when you try to extend Datapart1 volume?

Comment: If you post a link to the screen shot (imgur or whatever), I will edit it into your question.

Comment: [Can you describe what happens when you try to extend Datapart1 volume?]
Absolutely nothing, the option was grayed out

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the only way I was able to merged the extra space was;

1. Backup all the data on that partition.
2. Delete the partition
3. Create a new partition using all available space.
4. Then restore the volume backup.

The reason I had to do it this way is because Windows Server 2008 R2 does not let you have more than 4 partitions no matter what software you use i.e.: (partition magic). So the extra space I had created was unallocated and I could not initialize it or expand the existing partition.

Answer (score 0):

in the dell tools, adding a drive to an existing RAID5 group is considered a "RAID Level Migration" (exact wording depends on version), not an expansion. when you choose a RAID level migration, tell it you want RAID5, select the new drive as a member in addition to the existing 3, and it should restripe on to your new drive.

Comment: What I did was
1-Add the physical drive
2-Added it to the Raid5
3-Rebuild Raid5

Comment: did my answer guide you in the right direction? if so, please accept it as the correct answer by click on the checkmark to the left of my answer.